# Инициализация static-переменной класса для подсчёта количества вызовов метода

Tags: c++, наследование, static

Есть некоторый класс, в котором нужно подсчитать число вызовов конструктора копирования. У этого класса есть ещё два дочерних, в которых тоже нужно подсчитывать это же число. Необходимо использовать static-переменную для подсчёта вызовов.
Думаю, что static-переменная должна находится в protected-части базового класса, чтобы её могли унаследовать два производных. При этом столкнулся с проблемой: как инициализировать эту переменную (нулём), чтобы далее её увеличивать при каждом вызове конструктора?

Comment: Приведите ваш код

Comment: с новыми стандартами языка этот подход  сравним с проблемой кошки Шредингера (и парадоксом друга Винера). При в ведении такого побочного эффекта, либо количество реальных вызовов конструктора может увеличиться (если до этого контсрукторы не имели побочных эффектов), компилятор  имеет право его обойти и на разных компиляторах результаты (и быстродействие) могут быть разными. Если нужно гарантировать правильный подсчет, его нужно реализовывать через вывод в какую-то подсистему которая может считяться volatile а не хранить в статических переменных.

Comment: @Swift "нужно реализовывать через вывод в какую-то подсистему которая может считяться volatile а не хранить в статических переменных" — можно конкретней, что за подсистема?

Comment: @dIm0n это не конкретная подсистема, это то что требует стандарт как уcловие " не исключения" действий. Компилятор имеет право вносить любые измения в код, если они считаются "не наблюдаемыми". Т.е. не выводятся никуда, не записываются в файл, не передаются как аргумент в другую единицу (модуль - compilation unit ) или не записываются в volatile хранилище. Поэтому в стандарте есть примечание о возможности исключения побочных эффектов создания объектов. Подсчет объектов является своего рода регистрацией, вот и таковой паттерн и надо использовать , он описан у Банды Четырех.

Comment: @Swift про as-if и так понятно. Какой конкретно паттерн подойдёт в данной ситуации и чем он лучше статических переменных?

Comment: @dIm0n частный случай Observer'а, часто называемый self-registration. Так случай у них дан как часть "усовершенственного" Одиночки. Лучше он только грантированностью. Хуже он тем что он обязывает учитывать все временные объекты (что не всегда хорошо)

Comment: @Swift, как это понимать? Если временный объект создался, то он также и уничтожится через деструктор. Не создался - не будет вызван, ни конструктор, ни деструктор. Каким образом подсчёт может быть неправильным? Статическая переменная в классе - это по сути обычная глобальная переменная, но только с областью видимости класса (и плюс инкапсулированная).

Comment: @Swift, вы предлагаетет писать так: `inline static volatile int counter = 0;`?

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Да? Как насчет строчки `C c2 = C(arg);` ? Это эквивалент вызова `C::C(C(arg))`, но копирование может быть пропущено (elided) в принципе. Добавление счетчика либо не  заметит его либо добавит создание двух копий (и отсюда парадокс друга Вигнера - эксперимент не только повлиял на процесс но и внес неопределенность )

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον так можно , но некрасиво и неудобно, решение разбросано по коду. Как обрабатывать создание вложенных, скомпанованных, унаследованных объектов? Если мера нужна для архитектурного решения,  то лучше уж иметь обсервер который будет регистрировать создание объектов (и временные могут нас не волновать). Для отладки\анализа производительности? Полубесполезная мера.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Так:**

*test.hpp*

```
class Test
{
protected:
    inline static int counter = 0;
};
```

**Либо так:**

*test.hpp*

```
class Test
{
protected:
    static int counter;
};
```

*test.cpp*

```
int Test::counter = 0;
```

Comment: Тогда нужно указать тип для `Test::counter` в `test.cpp`.

Comment: @EOF, да, спасибо, забыл.

Answer (score 0):

При таком подходе:

```
class Base {
protected:
    static int nc;
public:
    Base() = default;
    Base(const Base&) { ++nc; }    
};
int Base::nc;

struct D1 : Base {    
    D1() = default;
    D1(const D1&) { ++nc; }
};


struct D2 : Base {    
    D2() = default;
    D2(const D2&) { ++nc; }
};
```

Вы не узнаете сколько раз были вызваны конструкторы копирования производных классов, потому что для всех будет только информация о том, сколько раз был вызван конструктор копирования базового класса. Правильнее, чтобы каждый класс(структура) имел свой счетчик:

```
struct Base {
    static int nc;
    Base() = default;
    Base(const Base&) { ++nc; }    
};
int Base::nc;

struct D1 : Base {
    static int nc;
    D1() = default;
    D1(const D1&) { ++nc; ++Base::nc; }
};
int D1::nc;

struct D2 : Base {
    static int nc;
    D2() = default;
    D2(const D2&) { ++nc; ++Base::nc; }
};
int D2::nc;
```

Тогда у нас будет полная информация о вызовах:

```
Base b;    
D1 d1;
D2 d2;
Base{ b }; //одна копия Base
D1{ d1 }, D1{ d1 }; //две копии
D2{ d2 }; // одна копия  D2
cout << Base::nc << "  копий базового класса\n"
     << D1::nc  << "  копий D1\n"
     << D2::nc  << "  копий D2\n";
```